# include library of functions in awk

Tags: awk

There are many common functions (especially arithmetic/mathematics) that are not built into `awk` that I need to write myself all the time.

For example:

1. There is no `c=min(a,b)`  , so in `awk` i constantly write `c=a<b?a:b`
2. same for maximum  i.e. `c=max(a,b)`
3. same for absolute value  i.e.  `c=abs(a)`  so i have to constantly write `c=a>0?a:-a`
4. and so on....

Ideally, I could write these functions into an `awk` source file, and "include" it into all of my instances of awk, so I can call them at will.

I looked into the "@include"  functionality of GNU's `gawk` , but it just executes whatever is in the included script - i.e. I cannot call functions.

I was hoping to write some functions in e.g.  `mylib.awk`, and then "include" this whenever I call `awk`.

I tried the `-f mylib.awk`  option to `awk`, but the script is executed - the functions therein are not callable.

Comment: little nitpick but abs should have >=0

Comment: @OlivierDulac : Does't make a difference, since -0 is equal to 0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
$ ls lib
prims.awk

$ cat lib/prims.awk
function abs(num) { return (num > 0 ? num : -num) }
function max(a,b) { return (a > b ? a : b) }
function min(a,b) { return (a < b ? a : b) }

$ export AWKPATH="$PWD/lib"

$ awk -i prims.awk 'BEGIN{print min(4,7), abs(-3)}'
4 3

$ cat tst.awk
@include "prims.awk"
BEGIN { print min(4,7), abs(-3) }

$ awk -f tst.awk
4 3
```

Comment: does not work.   the "-i" options is apparently uncredognized

Comment: Then you are not using gawk or you are using an old version and need to get a newer one (`-i` was introduced in gawk 4.1). The fact that you say `awk -f lib.awk -f script.awk` doesn't work for you either makes me thing you're just not using gawk, or the contents of your files are not what you want them to be.

Comment: good call, upgrading solved it.
  I am stunned (yet again), by how old some of the software is on my cluster.

Comment: I believe would be an interesting solution put this code in your profile file: `export AWKPATH="/path/to/awk/lib" ; alias primsawk="awk -i  $AWKPATH/prims.awk "`

Comment: You don't need to specify AWKPATH in the awk call, itd just be `awk -i prims.awk`

Answer (score 11):

You can have multiple `-f program-file` options, so one can be your common functions and the other can be a specific problem solving awk script, which will have access to those functions.

```
awk -f common-funcs.awk -f specific.awk file-to-process.txt
```

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but it's the best I've come up with. Here's an example:

```
$ cat common_func.awk
# Remove spaces from front and back of string
function trim(s) {
  gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", s);
  gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", s);
  return s;
}

$ cat specific.awk
{ print $1, $2 }
{ print trim($1), trim($2) }

$ cat file-to-process.txt 
abc    |    def   |

2$ awk -F\| -f common_func.awk -f specific.awk file-to-process.txt 
abc         def   
abc def
```

With regular awk (non-gnu) you can't mix the `-f program-file` option with an *inline* program.  That is, the following won't work:

```
awk -f common_func.awk '{ print trim($1) }' file-to-process.txt # WRONG
```

As pointed out in the comments, however, with gawk you can use the `-f` option together with `-e`:

```
awk -f file.awk -e '{stuff}' file.txt
```

Comment: just make the inline program behind the other `-f` files and it works with both `mawk` and `nawk` (and likely all `awk`s) ::::::::::::   ::::::   :::  ::::::  ::::::  :::::::::  ::::::::::::     :::::::::::   :  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::  ::::::    `mawk -f common_func.awk -f <( printf '%s' '{ print trim($0) }' )`

Answer (score 4):

In case if you can't use `-i` (if your `awk < 4.1` version ), which EdMorton suggested, make a try of below works with `GNU Awk 3.1.7`

> --source program-text
>
> Provide program source code in the program-text. This option allows you to mix source code in files with source code that you enter
>   on the command line. This is particularly useful when you have library
>   functions that you want to use from your command-line programs

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.

$ cat primes.awk 
function abs(num) { return (num > 0 ? num : -num) }
function max(a,b) { return (a > b ? a : b) }
function min(a,b) { return (a < b ? a : b) }

$ awk -f primes.awk --source 'BEGIN{print min(4,7), abs(-3)}'
4 3
```

Answer (score 2):

on regular awk (non gnu) you can still fake a bit using the shell using a cat of the file(s) into the 'code' (generally in front, but could be everywhere since it respect the awk way of working order)

```
> cat /tmp/delme.awk
   function PrintIt( a) { printf( "#%s\n", a )}

> echo "aze\nqsd" | awk "$( cat /tmp/delme.awk)"'{ sub( /./, ""); PrintIt( $0 )}'
#ze
#sd
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you can use the -i command line option or from inside a script the @include directive, but if you want a POSIX solution then awk -f functions.awk -f script.awk file.txt is the way you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

That was 2015. Today there is [cppawk](https://kylheku.com/cgit/cppawk/about) which combines the C preprocessor with Awk.
This gives you an `#include` mechanism that:

- Works in conjunction with multiple Awk implementation.
- Lets you capture the preprocessed output, to obtain a single Awk program that runs on systems without a C preprocessor
- Doesn't require an `AWKPATH` variable to know where the include files are. If `path/to/foo.awk` contains `#include "bar.awk"`, it will look for `path/to/bar.awk` for really easy bundling of library files.

cppawk is now [mentioned](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Versions) in the GNU Awk manual.

The specific functions referenced in the question can be written as macros:

```
cppawk '
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define abs(a) ((a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a))

... your code here
'
```

Only if you're feeling brave, though. These carry the disadvantages of hidden multiple evaluation. For instance, `max(a[i++], n)` produces undefined behavior (Awk has it!) and `max(fun1(), fun2())` will call a function twice.

No Awk implementation I know of inlines functions so this could speed up the code.

However, no Awk implementation I know of performs CSE (common subexpression elimination) so if the macros cause expensive functions to be called twice, that could slow down the code.