# How to inlcude functions from another file in a awk script using nextflow

Tags: awk, nextflow

As per the Nextflow documentation I put my awk scripts in the `bin/` folder. Some scripts share the same functions so I wrote a file with only awk functions that I usually include using:

```
@include "relative/path/to/lib.awk"
```

But because the script runs in the nextflow work directory the relative path doesn't work anymore. I tried to put the library file in `bin/` too but it didn't work as well.

How should I proceed? I don't want to copy/paste functions in the scripts, I also don't want to hardcode an absolute path.

Comment: can you use workflow.projectDir/path/to/awk ?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I didn't know about `workflow.projectDir`

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Pallie for the tip about `workflow.projectDir`. The documentation about this variable is [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/metadata.html) (I thought I looked everywhere, it was not clear I could do that), this answer also helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463193/2849598.

awk can load library files in `AWKPATH`, I have my file in `lib/` so, for the nextflow process:

```
process my_process {
  input:
  path input from input_channel

  output:
  path "output.txt"

  script:
  """
  export AWKPATH="$workflow.projectDir/lib"
  script.awk ${input} > output.txt
  """
}
```

and at the top of my script I call the library file like such

```
@include "my_functions.awk"
```